# Calculations of residue homomorphisms in cycle modules

Tags: algebraic-cycles, chow-groups

In the proof of Proposition 2.2 and Theorem 2.3 in Chow groups with coefficients https://eudml.org/doc/233731 written by M. Rost, he wrote

$\mathbb{A}^{1}={\rm Spec}F[u], \mathbb{A}^{2}={\rm Spec}F[s,t]$ and $Z=\mathbb{A}^{2}_{<s,t>}$, the localization of $\mathbb{A}^{2}$ at $0$. Let $y,z$ be points of $Z$ the points with parametetrs $s,t$ respectively. Then

\begin{align}
&\partial_{x}(\eta)=0 \text{ for }x \in Z^{(1)}\backslash\{y,z\},\\
&\partial_{y}(\eta)=-\{t\}r_{\kappa(y)\vert F}(\partial_{∞}(\rho)),\\
&\partial_{z}(\eta)=r_{\kappa(z)\vert F}\circ \partial_{0}(\{u\}･\rho)-\{s\}･r_{\kappa(z)\vert F}(\partial_{0}(\rho))\\
\end{align}

Q; Please calculation this formulae.